# How do I read using sscanf a character string with spaces and then a number?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I want to read from the keyboard data to be inserted in a list. 
For example if I type `ins "name_to_insert" 19930412`, the character string `name` should be name_to_insert, **without** the quotation marks and `date` should be 19930412.
I don't know how to properly specify the second sscanf.

```
char op[4], name[30], s[50];
int date;
while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s)==1)
{
    sscanf(s, "%s", op);
    if (strcmp(op, "ins")==0)
    {
        sscanf(s, "%*s %[^0-9]%d", name, &date);
        printf("Name is %s and date is %d\n", name, date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right. Assuming the quotes are mandatory, you simply need to wrap the scan-set conversion specifier in quotes:

```
if (sscanf(s, "%*s \"%29[^\"]\" %d", name, &date) != 2)
    ...oops...
```

Note the `%29[^0-9]`; this limits the string to 29 bytes plus the terminal null `'\0'` that will fit in your 30-byte array.  You should probably have a similar check on your outer `scanf()` too, or just use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` there.

If the quotes are optional, you have to work a little harder, scanning for the name as non-digits and removing the quotes after the scan:

```
if (sscanf(s, "%*s %29[^0-9] %d", name, &date) != 2)
    ...oops...
```

Here's some test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void scanner(const char *fmt, const char *s)
{
    char name[30];
    int  date;

    if (sscanf(s, fmt, name, &date) != 2)
        printf("Scan failed {%s} and {%s}\n", fmt, s);
    else
        printf("{%s} and {%s} => {%s} %d\n", fmt, s, name, date);
}

int main(void)
{
    char source[][30] =
    {
        "ins \"name in quotes\" 12345",
        "ins name without quotes 12345",
    };
    enum { NUM_SOURCE = sizeof(source) / sizeof(source[0]) };
    char format[][20] =
    {
        "%*s \"%29[^\"]\" %d",
        "%*s %29[^0-9] %d",
    };
    enum { NUM_FORMAT = sizeof(format) / sizeof(format[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FORMAT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_SOURCE; j++)
            scanner(format[i], source[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
{%*s "%29[^"]" %d} and {ins "name in quotes" 12345} => {name in quotes} 12345
Scan failed {%*s "%29[^"]" %d} and {ins name without quotes 12345}
{%*s %29[^0-9] %d} and {ins "name in quotes" 12345} => {"name in quotes" } 12345
{%*s %29[^0-9] %d} and {ins name without quotes 12345} => {name without quotes } 12345
```

The failed conversion is to be expected; the format looks for quotes and there aren't any.

I also played with a slightly different harness and the format string:

```
"%*s %1[\"]%29[^\"]%1[\"] %d"
```

(passing two 2-character strings, `q1` and `q2`, to hold the quotes), but when the quotes were missing, the scan failed; the quotes aren't optional.

Note that the name has the trailing space and the quotes with the second format; those will have to be removed separately.

Comment: If I drop the %*s, "ins" becomes part of the name. What can I do to ignore the quotes read from the keyboard?

Comment: Ah, beg your pardon; yes, the `%*s` is needed for that.  I'll update the answer...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with the quotes by simply removing the first and the last character from the name:

```
char op[4], nameTemp[30], *name, s[50];
int date;
while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s)==1)
{
    sscanf(s, "%s", op);
    if (strcmp(op, "ins")==0)
    {
        sscanf(s, "%*s %[^0-9]%d", nameTemp, &date);
        name=nameTemp+1;
        name[strlen(name)-2]='\0';
        printf("Name is %s and date is %d\n", name, date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sscanf(s, "%*s \"%[^\"]\" %d", name, &date);
```